# error while running my code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed:
>   uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in
>   library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1]
>   C:\Users\SANTOSH.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.0-alpha1.aar\92eaf7acf1e6b437bae2a0f4f84ceacf\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 9

Comment: The question itself shows uses-SDK:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 ..Declare the min SDK version as 14

Answer (score 1):

Update your **minSdkVersion** to **14** in **build.gradle** file.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE your app level gradle file, set **minSdkVersion 14**

**Try this,**

```
  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

After updating the gradle file, once clean and rebuild your project